# The Position Change Method of TabContainer of Dojo toolkit

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm using the tabContainer of dojo toolkit. 
If the tablist exceeds the range, there will be tablist_leftBtn and tablist_rightBtn. 
I want to know how to adjust the position of leftBtn.

[image]
I looked into the source code and it seemed to be controlled by ScrollingTabController, 
but I do not know how. I would appreciate your advice.

```
tabContainer = new TabContainer({
    style: "height: 800px; width: 100%;", 
    tabPosition: "bottom",
}, "tabContainer");

let tab = new ContentPane({
    id: "main", 
    title: "main",
    href: "/main", 
    closable: false
});
tabContainer.addChild(tab);
tabContainer.startup();
```

Comment: what you mean by ajust , what you want to do exactly ? capture would be appriciated

Comment: I add capture that shows left button and right button.

Comment: right , what do you wan to achieve ?

Comment: This is not possible out of the box. Just how Dojo TabContainer works. If you really need to change it you could possible extend the TabContainer to your own widget and hack your way into the existing code and styling. It shouldn't be that hard but I wouldn't recommend it at all.